# Starting a no card up front subscription using Laravel Cashier & Stripe

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, stripe-payments

I'm confused about how Cashier/Stripe subscriptions work with no card up front trials.
I have set the trial period on Stripe and created the plans.
I have set the no card up front model trait to false.

```
$user = User::find(1);

// This doesn't seem to do anything. No sub created in Stripe.

$user->subscription('yearly_uk');

// This throws an error as I am not passing through a card token.

$user->subscription('yearly_uk')->create();

// This throws an nasty api error but strangely does create a customer in Stripe.

$user->subscription('yearly_uk')->create(null);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm going to answer my own problem in the hope it helps someone else out. Taylor Otwell kindly pointed out you simply set the trial end date for no card up front customers. The Stripe account isn't actually created until the customer pays. The onTrial() function just checks this date and responds accordingly.

Comment: I am encountering a similar problem. I am trying to make Stripe charge customers from the first day of the next month. I have made it so Cashier sets the `trial_ends_at` field to the correct date (1st of next month) however even with the card up front trait set to false the customer is still billed instantly. Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 3):

By your comment, it looks like you've already answered this, but for future readers, I encountered a similar problem where the user can choose from a few plans, one of which is free.

To resolve, add this to your `User` Model:

```
protected $cardUpFront = false;
protected $trial_ends_at = null;
```

then you can subscribe the user using a null token:

```
$user->subscription('yearly_uk')->create(null);
```

I haven't checked, but I assume it won't throw the same kind of errors if / when you move to a paid plan - i.e. they'll be able to change, but I would guess Stripe will return an error as it'll bill the user with no credit card details.

Answer (score 0):

```
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $AuthUser = Auth::user();

    $stripe_plan = 'plan_CMFx07YJ96oL6h'; //Free stripe plan

    $user = User::find($user_id);
    $user->newSubscription('main',$stripe_plan)->create(null);

    if($AuthUser->subscribed('main')){
        return redirect('subscription')->with('status','You are subscribed successfully.');
    }
```

Comment: It's working but when I update any plan then it will not update we have to  create a new subscription.